# What APIs and Credentials are really needed for Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, api-key, firebase-analytics

After making an app for Firebase Analytics in Firebase Console (as mentioned here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) in old developers console (https://console.developers.google.com) for the respective project we get some APIs enabled automatically and some credentials:

API keys:

1. Server key (auto created by Google Service)
2. Android key (auto created by Google Service)

OAuth 2.0 client IDs:

3. Android client for xxx.xxx.xxx (auto created by Google Service)
4. Web client (auto created by Google Service)

Also there are 4 API enabled:

1. Google Cloud Messaging
2. Identity Toolkit API
3. Mobile Crash and Performance Reporting API
4. Token Service API.

> What of these API and Credentials are really needed for Firebase Analytics? I mean, do we need "Web client (auto created by Google Service)" client IDs or "Server key (auto created by Google Service)" if I plan using Analytic only?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need any of those to use Firebase Analytics.

Comment: Thank you for replay. So, I can delete those keys and disable the APIs and Firebase Analytic will have still work? One of those keys (Android key (auto created by Google Service) in JSON as api_key - current_key) actually mentioned in config. JSON file. Or Analytics does not use keys or APIs and uses only app's ID?

Comment: Analytics only requires the mobilesdk_app_id that is defined in the JSON file.

Comment: My android project refused to compile if 'api_key' array in JSON is empty (I used dependencies from https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). With that key it seems to compile and according to system logs my app sends data to Analytics. So, maybe we need at least that key?

Comment: You should not modify your JSON file.