# Deleting OAuth client 2.0 effects

Tags: android, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

According to [Firebase FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#android-sha1), adding a SHA-1 is only required if you are using either Firebase Invites or Firebase Dynamic Links and I think this also applies for Authentication as well.

Does that mean that if I remove my OAuth client ids in the [Google API console](http://console.developers.google.com/project), does it affect FCM and Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have seen this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443985/what-apis-and-credentials-are-really-needed-for-firebase-analytics?rq=1) in which I think answers the Analytics question, this only leaves the effects for Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, after some time searching in Firebase documents, I have encountered this [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials] saying about the need for OAuth 2.0 credentials. So what is the real thing?